# Multidimensional array problem with update_post_meta

Tags: user-meta

I have an issue saving a multi-dimensional array using update_post_meta.

Here's my code ($meta_key and $userID are set up above):

```
    $read_notices = get_user_meta($userID, $meta_key);

    if (null === $read_notices) {
        $read_notices = array();
    }

    $read_notices[] = $postID;

    update_user_meta($userID, $meta_key, $read_notices);
```

My problem is that the data is nesting every time so I end up with... Any ideas?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1823
                    )

                [1] => 1762
            )

        [1] => 1762
    )
)
```

Comment: `get_user_meta();` required a third argument as boolean like `get_user_meta($userID, $meta_key, true);`

Comment: Answered here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13353/problem-storing-arrays-with-update-user-meta?rq=1

It's important to add 'true' when getting the meta data so it isn't wrapped in an array. Phew.

EG:
    get_user_meta($userID, $meta_key, true);
not
    get_user_meta($userID, $meta_key);

EDIT: You guys were WAY too quick :)
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First af all `if (null === $read_notices)` is never `true`, because `get_user_meta` return false or empty string or empty array. Never return null.

Right way is check if it is empty:

```
if ( empty ($read_notices) ) { ... }
```

Then your problem is that using `get_user_meta` without passing the 3rd parameter as `true` will return a multidimensional array.

So right code for you scope is:

```
$read_notices = get_user_meta($userID, $meta_key, true) ? : array();
$prev = $read_notices;
$read_notices[] = $postID;
update_user_meta($userID, $meta_key, $read_notices, $prev);
```

Comment: you can't supply 3rd pram as prev value that's 4th, 3rd is value you want to save in `update_user_meta();`

Comment: Great response - I did find the answer (comment above) but you were quicker. Thanks G.M.

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to up-vote you :S

Comment: @Anjum +1 from me for your comment. Edited answer adding $prev value.

Comment: @rob_was_taken with edit by Anjum and mine now it should work.